# Function pointer pointing to member function

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm having trouble creating a plain old function pointer and assigning it to a member function from *myclass* object *obj*. I've copied a sample below,

```
class myclass
{
public:
myclass() { i = 38; }
int i;
void func() { cout << "inside func" << endl;  }
};

int main()
{
    myclass obj;
    myclass *objptr = &obj;

    int myclass::*iptr1; //decl pointer to member
    iptr1 = &myclass::i; //obtain offset
    cout << obj.*iptr1 << endl; //dereference using object; use .*
    cout << objptr->*iptr1 << endl; //dereference using pointer to object; use ->* 

    int *iptr2; //decl plain old integer pointer
    iptr2 = &obj.i; //obtain address of member
    cout << *iptr2 << endl; //dereference

    void(myclass::*fptr1)(); //decl pointer to member 
    fptr1 = &myclass::func; //obatain offset
    (obj.*fptr1)(); //dereference using object; use .*
    (objptr->*fptr1)(); //dereference using pointer to object; use ->* 

    /*void(*fptr2) (); // decl plain old function pointer
   fptr2 = obj.func; //this is the exact line that doesn't compile
   (*fptr2) ();*/ //after having a pointer to the member function *func* I would like to call it like this, if possible, from this plain old pointer

   getchar();
   return 0;

}
```

I get the following errors if the three line were uncommented

```
Error   C3867   'myclass::func': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a 
pointer to member   

Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall myclass::* )
(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

if not for the three lines I get the expected output

```
38
38
38
inside func
inside func
```

I need to get the third *inside func* using a plain old function pointer not a pointer to class member function. Need some help. Am I missing syntax here ?!

Comment: No, you're not missing any syntax – you can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func` is a non-static member function. It requires a `myclass` object to operate on (the one which `this` inside the function will then point to). That's as if the function had an invisible `myclass` argument.

`fptr2` is a function pointer for a function without any arguments, so the assignment is rejected. Here are some alternative solutions:

- Make `func` static.
- Change the type of `fptr2` to a pointer-to-member.
- Do not use raw function pointers; switch to C++11 lambdas and/or `std::function`.

Here is an example for the latter:

```
std::function<void()> f2;
f2 = [&]{ obj.func(); };
f2();
```